# USB порт дает питание, но не подключает клавиатуру/мышь. USB device not recognized

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, драйвер, железо

Проблема с Usb-портом. Питание он дает - телефон заряжает, флешки читает. Но мышку/клаву не подключает. Просидел всю ночь читая инфу по данной проблеме, перепробовал, вроде бы, все: обновлял/удалял/ещечтото драйвера в дейвайс менеджере, использовал софт типа USBOblivion, очищал реестор (вроде бы, там у меня не все гладко прошло, но я уверен что дело не в нем), отключил экономию энергии в рут хабе и хост контроллере, а так же поигрался в настройках батарей и энергии. Все ни о чем.
В итоге проверил на Ubuntu 16.04 - тоже самое, флешку видит, клавумышь нет. Значит, дело, вероятно, не в системе.

Прочитал где-то, что, может быть, проблема в биосе. Говорили обновить. Посмотрел, у меня стоит последняя версия, вроде как (мать TM1613).
Да и в моем биосе особо не разгуляешься.

Вообщем, прошу помощи, люди добрые! Может ли быть дело в железе?

Ошибка:
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Другую клаву\мышь пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata пробовал :)))))))))))))

Comment: А если подрубить активный usb-хаб и в него уже клаву\мышь?